# headerFormat and footerFormat in plotOptions.line.tooltip does not work for highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to attach a container to the tooltip with a class so that I can style it with css. But the header and the footer is not applied to the tooltip.

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {
            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<div class="test">',
              footerFormat: '</div>'
            }
          }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ad1bg7e/4/

Comment: It is working, but in highstock the header and the footer tooltip is split. see here for where the header shows up: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/6ad1bg7e/15/. Not sure where the footer is in this instance though. If you want the tooltip to be one place, you can set `tooltip: {split: false}`, it would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/6ad1bg7e/17/

Comment: I want to add a div wrapper such that I can style it based on class, but the div does not get applied. Does that mean that headerFormat and footerFormat are not meant for that purpose?

Comment: You can, you just need to enable it with [useHTML](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.useHTML) see here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/6ad1bg7e/28/